# How to create Left Tabber content

Tags: php, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I want to create a left tabber content for my frontpage. I am using this website 
[Click Here](http://www.bootply.com/74926)

But When i add code in my single.php and style.css file it not working like in actual preview. My theme is not build on bootstrap.

I want to create a Left Tabber like this [Screen Shot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QYFPB.png)

Please help me in this issue.

Comment: Are you using bootstrap?

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```css
.tabs-left > .nav-tabs {
  border-bottom: 0;
}

.tab-content > .tab-pane,
.pill-content > .pill-pane {
  display: none;
}

.tab-content > .active,
.pill-content > .active {
  display: block;
}

.tabs-left > .nav-tabs > li {
  float: none;
}

.tabs-left > .nav-tabs > li > a {
  min-width: 74px;
  margin-right: 0;
  margin-bottom: 3px;
}

.tabs-left > .nav-tabs {
  float: left;
  margin-right: 19px;
  border-right: 1px solid #ddd;
}

.tabs-left > .nav-tabs > li > a {
  margin-right: -1px;
  -webkit-border-radius: 4px 0 0 4px;
     -moz-border-radius: 4px 0 0 4px;
          border-radius: 4px 0 0 4px;
}

.tabs-left > .nav-tabs > li > a:hover,
.tabs-left > .nav-tabs > li > a:focus {
  border-color: #eeeeee #dddddd #eeeeee #eeeeee;
}

.tabs-left > .nav-tabs .active > a,
.tabs-left > .nav-tabs .active > a:hover,
.tabs-left > .nav-tabs .active > a:focus {
  border-color: #ddd transparent #ddd #ddd;
  *border-right-color: #ffffff;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<!-- Optional theme -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!-- Latest compiled and minified JavaScript -->
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<div class="row">    
    <div class="col-md-12"><h3>Tabs -left</h3>
      <!-- tabs left -->
      <div class="tabbable tabs-left">
        <ul class="nav nav-tabs">
          <li><a href="#a" data-toggle="tab">One</a></li>
          <li class="active"><a href="#b" data-toggle="tab">Two</a></li>
          <li><a href="#c" data-toggle="tab">Twee</a></li>
        </ul>
        <div class="tab-content">
         <div class="tab-pane active" id="a">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, charetra varius quam sit amet vulputate. 
         Quisque mauris augue, molestie tincidunt condimentum vitae, gravida a libero.</div>
         <div class="tab-pane" id="b">Secondo sed ac orci quis tortor imperdiet venenatis. Duis elementum auctor accumsan. 
         Aliquam in felis sit amet augue.</div>
         <div class="tab-pane" id="c">Thirdamuno, ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Duis pharetra varius quam sit amet vulputate. 
         Quisque mauris augue, molestie tincidunt condimentum vitae. </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <!-- /tabs -->  
    </div>
```

Comment: your code works perfectly and I have implemented on my website. My last question is this is the preview of website from where i originally get the idea ... this is the screenshot : http://prntscr.com/86d55h

But on responsive design this website uses a menu type system and all the left sided content are display in a menu style ... see this : http://prntscr.com/86d5d0

please can you help me how to do this ... the original website is ratemds.com

Comment: Thanks @gamitg ... with your help I have created what i want ... thanks alot guider :)